# How to get the AUTOINC value when connecting via ADO?

Tags: delphi, ado, auto-increment, advantage-database-server

I am trying to connect my database (Advantage 7.1 Server) using the Advantage OLE DB provider. So far so good...It connects with no problem with the code below:-

```
const
  // the database we'll be connecting to 
  ConnectionString = 'Provider=Advantage OLE DB Provider;Data Source=C:\Data\'+
  'UsersData.add;ServerType=ADS_REMOTE_SERVER|ADS_LOCAL_SERVER;User ID=ISUsers;Password=aAoO31';
```

My problem is, even though I'm able to connect to the database, any field with AUTOINC as the data type does not generate next numbers. "ID" as AUTOINC keeps on giving me zero (0) anytime I append the data instead of moving to the next number 1, 2, 3.... But for the same code if I switch to MS ACCESS, it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? please find code below.

```
    // Add template to database. Returns added template ID.
function TDBClass.addTemplate(template: TTemplate): Integer;
var
  rs: TADODataSet;
  tptStream: TMemoryStream;
  id: Integer;
  p: PChar;
begin
  // get DB data and append one row
  rs := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  rs.Connection := connection;
  rs.CursorType := ctStatic;
  rs.LockType := ltOptimistic;
  rs.CommandText := 'SELECT * FROM enroll';
  rs.Open();
  rs.Append();
  tptStream := TMemoryStream.Create();
  // write template data to memory stream.
  SafeArrayAccessData(template.tpt, Pointer(p));
  tptStream.write(p^, template.size);
  SafeArrayUnaccessData(template.tpt);
  // save template data from memory stream to database.
  (rs.FieldByName('template') as  TBlobField).LoadFromStream(tptStream);
  // update the database with added template.
  rs.post();
  // get the ID of enrolled template.
  id := rs.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;
  // close connection
  tptStream.Free();
  rs.Close();
  rs.Free();
  addTemplate := id;
end;
```

Comment: I am not familiar with Advantage and this post is rather old: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/Content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=030606-1534

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using the `TADSConnection`, `TADSQuery`, etc. components that you can still download from the DevZone (http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=1) even for ADS 7.1.

If you have to use ADO, you probably have to use a different approach. (But see also bummi's comment about a possible bug in Delphi).

One way would be to use the `LASTAUTOINC` scalar function:

```
INSERT INTO
  enroll
(
  template
)
VALUES
(
  :template
);

SELECT
  LASTAUTOINC(CONNECTION) AS "id"
FROM
  system.iota
```

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi ADO you can pass more than 1 statement in your SQL query string - This might true for ADO in general.

> > Insert into test (text) Values('ddd'); Select * from test where AutoIncColumn = Scope_identity()

This will return the inserted row with the Autoinc value

or if you need just the autoinc value

> > Insert into test (text) Values('ddd'); Select Scope_identity() AutoIncColumn